# Removing IIS server from my machine so that Apache may access port 80

Tags: apache-2.2, iis

My title is pretty self explanatory, but I would like to go into detail about my issue.  My home computer had an IIS server installed a while back and it automatically began listening on port 80.  I have tried to find every instance of the server and delete it from my machine, but it's still there.  Now that I have an Apache server installed, I had to have it listen on a different port.  This isn't that big of a deal, it's more of an inconvenience.  I'd like for my Apache server to listen on port 80, not the IIS server.  So, do I make that happen?

Comment: Have you try to uninstall IIS?

Comment: @masegaloeh Read my question and you'll have your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your RUN, go to services.msc

Then, find and DISABLE the IIS Admin service. If you just stop it for now and the next time you reboot your machine/server, the service *might* be started again. So, make sure you stop and disable that service for good.

Answer (score 0):

You can stop iis service. 
net stop iisadmin /y

Comment: I'm guessing I do that from the command line?  Is that a Linux command string or windows?  I'm using a windows system

Comment: That's a Windows command line, yes.